# Search a string in multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using the following formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(LOOKUP(2^15;SEARCH(MID(A1;1;9);$D$1:$D$100)));"No";"Yes")
```

this is working perfectly!

*Question*: I want to search within **columns $D$1:$E$100** and not only one column **D**. How can I modify this to search in two columns?

Comment: As a side note, [LOOKUP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheetfunction.lookup.aspx) is a backwards compatibility artifact. HLOOKUP, VLOOKUP, and MATCH w/ INDEX are better lookup methods for general use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to `AND` the results of a search in each column. This translates to "if not found in D and not found in E then output No". The logic is as follows:

```
In column D | ISERROR(lookup in D) | In Column E | ISERROR(lookup in E) | result
   N        |         Y            |     N       |         Y            |  No
   N        |         Y            |     Y       |         N            |  Yes
   Y        |         N            |     N       |         Y            |  Yes
   Y        |         N            |     Y       |         N            |  Yes
```

```
=IF(AND(ISERROR(LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH(MID(A1,1,9),$D$1:$D$100))),
ISERROR(LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH(MID(A1,1,9),$E$1:$E$100)))),"No","Yes")
```